# How can I send HTML emails using PHP through a diffrent server to avoid Shared-hosting delays

Tags: smtp, html-email, shared-hosting, dkim, mx-record

I am currently using SiteGround shared hosting to host my website. Through SiteGround I send an HTML email using PHP to my customers when they register to confirm their email address.

I am currently having issues with receiving email, with it taking over 4 hours to appear in my inbox.
Contacting Siteground they tell me SpamExperts who run their MX recorders are having some issues. I am currently still having these issues after 24 hours despite Siteground telling me it has been fixed.

I am unsure about how to fix this, it may just need time. Either way, I was wondering if there is any way of having an alternative server to send my emails through incase it happens again?

I have limited knowledge on how emails send, but I know that it helps if the from the domain name is the same one I have set up through the shared hosting. I thought about just having shared hosting with another company but then my domain wouldn't match up.

I'd appreciate any insight into this.

Comment: You can sign up for any cloud hoster's smtp service, configure your code to use the new smtp server, and you're done. I may or may not have understood what you are asking, though.

Comment: Thanks, @Robert I managed to get it working with an SMTP service and sent the emails successfully.